# Matlab poison and figures

Tags: image, matlab, variables, plot, screen-capture

3 Matlab questions

1 - Does anyone know if there is an equivalent to

```
#pragma GCC poison variable_name
```

in matlab, i.e. it causes matlab to error if it finds variable_name being used from this point onwards in the code?

Two other less related questions, as i still can't believe it.

2 - Is there anyway to link commands like

```
imagesc(I1_avg_crop, [bg_value multiplier2*std_value+bg_value]);
```

to a figure in particular, other than doing

```
set(0,'CurrentFigure',fig3);
imagesc(I1_avg_crop, [bg_value multiplier2*std_value+bg_value]);
```

immediately before it?

3 - can getframe() (or similar) actually get whats in a figure rather than "doing a screen capture"?, as it doesn't work so well when the figure window is moved?

(I'm editing someones code, and i am new to matlab, so i apologise in advance if these are stupid questions, its just i can't locate what i want in the documentation)

EDIT: Extra Question
The manual says

```
set(0,'CurrentFigure',h);
```

Makes the figure h current, but do not change its visibility or stacking with respect to other figures. Does this still apply on Mac OS X as it seems to still force it to the top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) No, it isn't possible to "natively" poison a variable. However, you can do the following workaround: Define a class like this:

```
classdef poison 
   properties (SetAccess=private)
      varName
   end
   methods
     function obj = poison(varName)
        obj.varName = varName;
     end
     function delete(obj)
        error('attempting to overwrite ''%s''',obj.varName)
     end
   end
end
```

Then you can call `variable_name = poison('variable_name')` and get the same effect - if `variable_name` is overwritten, it triggers the object's delete method and throws an error, if there is an attempt at indexing, or at arithmetic manipulation, there are generic errors.

(2) You can set the parent of the image explicitly (pass an axes handle, which you can e.g. obtain by `axHandle = axes('Parent',fig3);`) in the function call, which avoids calling the figure. However, you cannot do that *and* set colormap scaling. Thus, you have to either use

```
imshow(I1_avg_crop,[bg_value multiplier2*std_value+bg_value],'Parent',axHandle);
```

or, if you don't have acces to the image processing toolbox, you need to use `image`

```
image(I1_avg_crop, 'CDataMapping','scaled','Parent',axHandle);
set(axHandle,'clim',[bg_value multiplier2*std_value+bg_value])
```

(3) If you call `getframe` with an axes handle, it should be able to capture the contents of the axes - unless you moved the figure onto the second screen, in which case it won't work. BTW: I have noticed `getframe` to have issues on OSX in the past, e.g. with docked figures.

(4) There are, at times OSX-specific issues with Matlab, as they are still debugging some of the very basic stuff (the OSX version used to be the Linux version running in X-Windows, and they've been working on changing that for the last few years).

Comment: just incase anyone else looks at this "Private", should have a lowercase 'p'

Comment: @Twig: You should report issue #4 to MathWorks - they won't fix bugs they never hear about.

Comment: for (3) i was using the axeshandle, but when i look at the saved movie, in frames in which the window was moved, it shows bits of window, and bits of what was underneath.

Comment: @Jonas: (2) doesn't seem to work. The figure window loads, but then it doesn't put anything inside it.

Comment: it breaks on " hh = image(varargin{:},'CDataMapping','scaled');" in file imagesc.m with error http://pastebin.com/kEHEdZfH

Comment: @Twig: oops, sorry about that. It's the axes handle you have to pass as a parent. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: @Jonas: still fails, this time with http://pastebin.com/vPwcSt76 on same line and file

Comment: @Twig: Apologies. I never use `imagesc`, and falsely assumed that it would have a similarly convenient syntax as `imshow` (from the image processing toolbox). You can't actually do it by calling `imagesc` but it will work by calling `image`, which is the function called by `imagesc`. Note that `imshow` uses grayscale colormap by default, instead of `jet`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: @jonas: image seems to have the same problem, works with imshow though. thanks

Comment: @Twig: Really? The command as in my solution works for me with `image`. Note that you have to set the min/max scaling separately.

Answer (score 0):

Point (3 & 4) was because i was using getframe to get an image and this forced the window to be brought to the frount, so it could do a screenshot of it. I have now found a solution by using http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/avifile.addframe.html which is far superior to getframe as it can can take a "figure or axis handle h".

```
fig4 = figure('Position',[450 300 400 round(400*aspect_ratio)],'Name','fig4'); % figure 4
aviobj = avifile(movie_name,'compression','None');
    for i = 1:N
        aviobj = addframe(aviobj,fig4);
    end
aviobj = close(aviobj);
```

its important to close it, as otherwise it doesn't save the image. Also apparently doesn't suffer from the screensaver problem.

Comment: It is best to have the 'Resize','off' options for the figure as well, otherwise it will error, if the window is resized.